# TcpStream::connect - match arms have incompatible type

Tags: sockets, networking, rust, match

I'm trying to write basic networking code in Rust, but running into an error I don't understand. I have been using match statements to error check everything in Rust so far, but when I try to error check TcpStream::connect(), I get an unexpected error:

My code:

```
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let mut server = match TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:23456"){
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(x) => println!("Could not connect to server: {x}"),
    };
}
```

The compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:8:19
  |
6 |       let mut server = match TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:23456"){
  |  ______________________-
7 | |         Ok(x) => x,
  | |                  - this is found to be of type `TcpStream`
8 | |         Err(x) => println!("Could not connect to server: {x}"),
  | |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                        expected struct `TcpStream`, found `()`
9 | |     };
  | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
  |
```

Every other time I use a match statement it allows me to destructure the Result type into a return value in the OK case (as above), or an error string in the error case.

It is the case that TcpStream::connect() returns a TcpStream, but why is the compiler insisting that the error case also needs to return a TcpStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `match` statement gets assigned to `server`.

However, both branches of your `match` statement return a different type.

- `Ok(x)` returns `x`, which is of type `TcpStream`.
- `Err(x)` returns the result of `println!()`, which has the return value `()`.

`TcpStream` and `()` are incompatible.

Just think about the code after the match statement. What should the `server` variable be? You don't stop the execution when the error happens, you simply `println!()` and continue. So **something** has to be written to the `server` variable.

If you `panic!()` instead of `println!()`, meaning print and abort, then it compiles because it knows that the `Err` case won't continue afterwards:

```rust
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let mut server = match TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:23456") {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(x) => panic!("Could not connect to server: {x}"),
    };
}
```

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not connect to server: Connection refused (os error 111)', src/main.rs:6:19
```

That said, if this is your desired behavior, there is a short form for it:

```rust
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let mut server = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:23456").expect("Could not connect to server");
}
```

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not connect to server: Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }', src/main.rs:4:60
```

---

I recommend handling the error properly, though.

There are many ways to do that, so this part will be opinionated.

I personally like [`miette`](https://docs.rs/miette) (an alternative would be [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow)):

```rust
use miette::{Context, IntoDiagnostic};
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() -> miette::Result<()> {
    let mut _server = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:23456")
        .into_diagnostic()
        .wrap_err("Could not connect to server.")?;

    // Do something with server

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Error: 
  × Could not connect to server.
  ╰─▶ Connection refused (os error 111)
```

Comment: That's exactly right. In my other match statements I've been calling return to quit on an error. The Rust compiler continues to surprise me.

Comment: @David added recommendation for error handling

Comment: Thanks for the reccomendation- I was using match so I could keep some control over error handling (at least until I got comfortable). I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @David I do recommend getting comfortable with the `?` operator. As shown, you can use error wrapping if you want to add your own output to it, but the questionmark operator makes code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your `server` variable can't be both `TcpStream` and the unit type `()`

Try propagating the error instead.

Here is an example from [the official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html):

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:34254")?;

    stream.write(&[1])?;
    stream.read(&mut [0; 128])?;
    Ok(())
}
```

If it can't connect to the server, it emits an error message

```
Error: Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }
```

And sets a non-zero exit code

```
$ echo $?
1
```