# How call function on Err arm

Tags: rust

I wrote this code and it works. But I have a custom class for outputting logs to stdout. I want to call my logging function if I get an Error instead of panic! macro.

```rust
fn create_logfile() -> File {
    let timestamp = Log::format_date(chrono::Local::now());
    let filename = format!("{}.log", timestamp);
    let logfile = match File::create(filename) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(error) => {
            panic!("There was a problem creating the file: {:?}", error)
        }
    };
    logfile
}
```

For example I want get something like that:

```rust
    let logfile = match File::create(filename) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(e) => {
            Log::error("Log file creation failed, reason: {}", e);
            process::exit(1)
        }
    };
```

But compiler says:

```
[E0308] `match` arms have incompatible types.
[Note] expected struct `File`, found `()
```

How can I solve this problem?
If I put the error data to stderr will it help?

Comment: Neither of your examples shows the error you talk about. However both have a return type of `!` aka they don't return at all in the `Err` case, they abort. Your code needs to do that as well, or it needs to return a value of the same type in both arms, either by actually doing that, or by using a "unifying" enum such as a `Result` or an `Either`. Either way without the actual code it's difficult to provide more assistance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including necessary `use`-statements and the full error message.

Comment: This is something that being asked quite often. The first commenter is right, both arms have to return possible values of Result.
You may find these question and answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75354551/1173020 (try propagating error instead of panicking).

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a21afd9a4dcc0407a5bd8cc449e9512), since `!` coerces to any type.

Comment: @denis.peplin Yes, if I use Result<File, Error> it should work, but it propagates the error to the calling function and I have to handle the error on the calling function side. I want to do something a little different - return <File> from the function if all is ok or print the reason of the error to stdout and kill the process. May be have any ideas?

Comment: @cafce25 I figured out what's wrong, Err arm is waiting for either an error return or process termination. That is, Err must be sure that the program will not continue until the error has been processed.

Comment: `Err` is not the blocking factor here -- it is the type-checking on the arms of the `match` block. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your revised example with `std::process::exit()` works for me: ([link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7af241b4415fd26a12bcfaf659e75459))

```rust
use chrono; // 0.4.23
use std::fs::File;
use log; // 0.4.17

struct Log { }

impl Log {
    fn format_date(date: chrono::DateTime<chrono::offset::Local>) -> i64 {
        return 0; 
    }
}

fn old_create_logfile() -> File {
    let timestamp = Log::format_date(chrono::Local::now());
    let filename = format!("{}.log", timestamp);
    let logfile = match File::create(filename) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(error) => {
            panic!("There was a problem creating the file: {:?}", error)
        }
    };
    logfile
}

fn new_create_logfile() -> File {
    let timestamp = Log::format_date(chrono::Local::now());
    let filename = format!("{}.log", timestamp);
     let logfile = match File::create(filename) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(e) => {
            // Instead of using `Log::error`, we'll use `log::error!` for show.
            log::error!("Log file creation failed, reason: {}", e);
            // This compiles.
            std::process::exit(1)
        }
    };
    logfile
}

fn main() {
    new_create_logfile();
}
```

Normally, you need to make sure the return types of all `match` arms have the same type -- here, you are returning `std::fs::File` under the `Ok` branch, so the `Err` branch can "escape" the requirement by returning `!` (pronounced "never") ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html)).

Since computation never returns from the `std::process::exit()` and its return type is marked as `!`, it passes the type-checking stage.